# How do I select a value from array object in a tag dropdown angular 8?

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-ngmodel

I try to select the values ​​from a dropdown, which I get from the database.
Let's say we have a saved record in DB already:

```
[
    {
        "value": "1",
        "label": "TBP_01"
    },
    {
        "value": "2",
        "label": "TBP_02"
    }
]
```

> ts

```
  export interface IOption {
    label: string;
    value: string; 
  }

  public data: IOption[] = [{
        "value": "1",
        "label": "TBP_01"
    },
    {
        "value": "2",
        "label": "TBP_02"
    },
    {
        "value": "3",
        "label": "TBP_03"
    },
    {
        "value": "4",
        "label": "TBP_04"
    }
  ];

  public savedData: IOption[] = [
    {
        "value": "1",
        "label": "TBP_01"
    },
    {
        "value": "2",
        "label": "TBP_02"
    }
  ];

 onChange(value: any, index: number) {
    this.savedData[index] = value;
  }
```

Two dropdowns are generated from the saved data set.

> html

```
<div *ngFor="let item of savedData; let i=index">
  <select
    class="form-control"
    name="{{configParams[2].key}}_{{i}}"
    [required]="configParams[0].required"
    [(ngModel)]="item"
    (ngModelChange)="onChange(item, i)">
    <option [ngValue]=opt
       *ngFor="let opt of tbsData"
       [selected]="opt.label === item.label">
       {{opt.label}}{{item.label===opt.label}}
    </option>
  </select>
<(div>
```

Everything works fine so far. Selecting and storing. But what does not work is preselecting the stored value.

[image]

I would expect this:

[image]

I use Angular 8. I would be happy for a hint.

I have now added the following code to  to see if the comparison works at all.

```
{{opt.label}} {{opt.value === item.value}}
```

[image]

.. and yes, basically it would work.

Comment: Try replacing `[(ngModel)]="item"` with `[(ngModel)]="item.label"`.

Comment: @MichaelD yes, but then only item.label is adjusted for savedData, but I need value and label.

Comment: OK, thats not working with two way binding.

Answer (score 0):

I highly recommend you to use ng-select;

but for this case, change

```
([ngMode])=item
```

to

```
[ngModel]="tbsData"
```

Answer (score 0):

I removed the two-way binding and the changes are:

```
<select
  class="form-control"
  name="{{configParams[2].key}}_{{i}}"
  [required]="configParams[0].required"
  **(change)="onChange($event, i)">**
  <option [ngValue]=opt
          *ngFor="let opt of tbsData"
          [selected]="opt.label === item.label">
    {{opt.label}}
  </option>

  onChange(event, index: number) {
    const selectElement = event.target;
    const optionIndex = selectElement.selectedIndex;
    this.relationToTbsArray[index] = this.tbsData.find(data => data.label === selectElement.value);
  }
```

This is how it works as I expected. The saved value is now selected in the dropdown.

I'm not sure if this is a clean way. I'm still learning.